# How to use very large dataset in RNN TensorFlow?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, data-processing

I have a very large dataset: 7.9 GB of CSV files. 80% of which shall serve as the training data, and the remaining 20% shall serve as test data. When I'm loading the training data (6.2 GB), I'm having `MemoryError` at the 80th iteration (80th file). Here's the script I'm using in loading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

col_names = ['duration', 'service', 'src_bytes', 'dest_bytes', 'count', 'same_srv_rate',
        'serror_rate', 'srv_serror_rate', 'dst_host_count', 'dst_host_srv_count',
        'dst_host_same_src_port_rate', 'dst_host_serror_rate', 'dst_host_srv_serror_rate',
        'flag', 'ids_detection', 'malware_detection', 'ashula_detection', 'label', 'src_ip_add',
        'src_port_num', 'dst_ip_add', 'dst_port_num', 'start_time', 'protocol']

# create a list to store the filenames
files = []

# create a dataframe to store the contents of CSV files
df = pd.DataFrame()

# get the filenames in the specified PATH
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    ''' Append to the list the filenames under the subdirectories of the <path> '''
    files.extend(os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames)

for file in files:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file, names=col_names, engine='python'))
    print('Appending file : {file}'.format(file=files[index]))

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
print(df)
```

There are 130 files in the 6.2 GB worth of CSV files.

Comment: how about dealing with terabytes of data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For large datasets - and we may already count 6.2GB as large - reading all the data in at once might not be the best idea. As you are going to train your network batch by batch anyway, it is sufficient to only load the data you need for the batch which is going to be used next.

The [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) provides a good overview on how to implement a data reading pipeline. Stages according to the documentation linked are:

> 1. The list of filenames
> 2. Optional filename shuffling
> 3. Optional epoch limit
> 4. Filename queue
> 5. A Reader for the file format
> 6. A decoder for a record read by the reader
> 7. Optional preprocessing
> 8. Example queue

Comment: how about dealing with terabytes of data?

Comment: @RemisHaroon Same answer: process your data batchwise. If you cannot load even a single file due to memory constraints, try splitting your data files and think about more efficient data representations.

Comment: OK, split data, but how ? manually? or is there already a tool for it? , OK, then after splitting what? process batches sequentially? or parallel distributed way? is there any tool/framework for that?

Answer (score 6):

I second Nyps's answer, I just don't have enough reputation to add a comment just yet. Additionally, it might be interesting for you to open Task Manager or equivalent and observe the used memory of your system as you run this. I would guess that when your RAM entirely fills up, that's when you're getting your error.

TensorFlow supports queues, which allow you to only read portions of data at once, in order to not exhaust your memory. Examples for this are in the documentation that Nyps linked. Also, TensorFlow has recently added a new way to handle input datasets in [TensorFlow Dataset docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

Also, I would suggest converting all your data to TensorFlow's TFRecord format, as it will save space, and can speed up data accessing over 100 times compared to converting CSV files to tensors at training time.

Comment: Thank you, @John Scolaro. I was already reading up on the documentation that Nyps posted even before I asked my question here. But haven't finished reading it just yet. Thank you both! :)

Comment: Observing the memory is definitely a good point. One might mention that 8GB of RAM often won't be enough to load 6.xGB of data as the RAM is also used by other programs.

Comment: Yep. :) Especially if it is a CSV file, because the CSV processing functions in TensorFlow add more overhead again.

Comment: I am now writing a script to convert my CSV files to TFRecords. Thank you! Will update you soon! :)

Comment: Good luck friend!

Comment: Is it normal for a TFRecord to be larger than the original files? In my case, the CSV files.

Comment: I don't think so. Mine all compressed down to about 80% of the original file size. My data is mostly float32's.

Comment: I posted  another question, and the answer by vijay m implies that it's not recommended for my dataset to be converted to CSV since there are a lot of features. The question's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360059/converting-csv-files-to-tf-records/45360578#45360578

Comment: how about dealing with terabytes of data?