# Converting CSV files to TF Records

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, file-io, dataset

I've been running my script for more than 5 hours already. I have 258 CSV files that I want to convert to TF Records. I wrote the following script, and as I've said, I've been running it for more than 5 hours already:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
import standardize_data
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None
PATH = '/home/darth/GitHub Projects/gru_svm/dataset/train'

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def convert_to(dataset, name):
    """Converts a dataset to tfrecords"""

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(dataset)

    # TF reader
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()

    # default values, in case of empty columns
    record_defaults = [[0.0] for x in range(24)]

    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    duration, service, src_bytes, dest_bytes, count, same_srv_rate, \
    serror_rate, srv_serror_rate, dst_host_count, dst_host_srv_count, \
    dst_host_same_src_port_rate, dst_host_serror_rate, dst_host_srv_serror_rate, \
    flag, ids_detection, malware_detection, ashula_detection, label, src_ip_add, \
    src_port_num, dst_ip_add, dst_port_num, start_time, protocol = \
    tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    features = tf.stack([duration, service, src_bytes, dest_bytes, count, same_srv_rate,
                        serror_rate, srv_serror_rate, dst_host_count, dst_host_srv_count,
                        dst_host_same_src_port_rate, dst_host_serror_rate, dst_host_srv_serror_rate,
                        flag, ids_detection, malware_detection, ashula_detection, src_ip_add,
                        src_port_num, dst_ip_add, dst_port_num, start_time, protocol])

    filename = os.path.join(FLAGS.directory, name + '.tfrecords')
    print('Writing {}'.format(filename))
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                example, l = sess.run([features, label])
                print('Writing {dataset} : {example}, {label}'.format(dataset=sess.run(key),
                        example=example, label=l))
                example_to_write = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'duration' : _float_feature(example[0]),
                    'service' : _int64_feature(int(example[1])),
                    'src_bytes' : _float_feature(example[2]),
                    'dest_bytes' : _float_feature(example[3]),
                    'count' : _float_feature(example[4]),
                    'same_srv_rate' : _float_feature(example[5]),
                    'serror_rate' : _float_feature(example[6]),
                    'srv_serror_rate' : _float_feature(example[7]),
                    'dst_host_count' : _float_feature(example[8]),
                    'dst_host_srv_count' : _float_feature(example[9]),
                    'dst_host_same_src_port_rate' : _float_feature(example[10]),
                    'dst_host_serror_rate' : _float_feature(example[11]),
                    'dst_host_srv_serror_rate' : _float_feature(example[12]),
                    'flag' : _int64_feature(int(example[13])),
                    'ids_detection' : _int64_feature(int(example[14])),
                    'malware_detection' : _int64_feature(int(example[15])),
                    'ashula_detection' : _int64_feature(int(example[16])),
                    'label' : _int64_feature(int(l)),
                    'src_ip_add' : _float_feature(example[17]),
                    'src_port_num' : _float_feature(example[18]),
                    'dst_ip_add' : _float_feature(example[19]),
                    'dst_port_num' : _float_feature(example[20]),
                    'start_time' : _float_feature(example[21]),
                    'protocol' : _int64_feature(int(example[22])),
                    }))
                writer.write(example_to_write.SerializeToString())
            writer.close()
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Done converting -- EOF reached.')
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        coord.join(threads)

def main(unused_argv):
    files = standardize_data.list_files(path=PATH)

    convert_to(dataset=files, name='train')
```

It already got me thinking that perhaps it's stuck in an infinite loop? What I want to do is to read all rows in each CSV file (258 CSV files), and write those rows into a TF Record (a feature and a label, that is, of course). And then, stop the loop when there are no more rows available, or the CSV files have been exhausted already.

The `standardize_data.list_files(path)` is a function I wrote in a different module. I just re-used it for this script. What it does is to return a list of all the files found in `PATH`. Take note that the files in my `PATH` only contains CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `num_epochs=1` in `string_input_producer`. Another note: Converting these `csv` to tfrecords may not offer any advantage you are looking in tfrecords, the overheads is very high with this kind of data (with the large number of single features/labels). You may want to experiment this part.

Comment: So, in other words, are you not suggesting to convert them to TF Records?

Comment: Do this experiment: convert just one file and then check the respective sizes. Your data is such that its not efficient for `tfrecords` representation. Every feature is saved along with the label, so i guess is that it will have a very large size than keeping it as csv.

Comment: A sample CSV file is 10.1 MB, its tfrecord equivalent is 9.6 MB

Comment: Not sure why its less. Isn't it every sample in csv is a float separated by comma (ignoring the headers which are saved in the first line), but every sample in tfrecord in this case is a 'key:value' pair, so shouldn't it be large?

Comment: I've converted other values to int64 instead of float. I think that would count as to why it's less. What do you think?

Comment: But what do you recommend? Use the CSV files as they are in my neural net training?

Comment: Here's a sample data I uploaded to GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/AFAgarap/61b17a3f02a9e13eb0c7aad9406a3408

Comment: I looked at the file, you are writing each column, instead of each row. Thats why its efficient in memory size.. But how were you able to read the records in batches during training, you read the entire file as a batch?

Comment: My problem with this is solved already. But to answer your question, I followed the reading of CSV files here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#file_formats. Then I just decided not to convert the CSV to TFRecords since my presentation is on Friday. Thank you! :)

Comment: Check out the new `Dataset API`, its a life saver. If you want to use tfrecords for your case, then you can convert it to a numpy matrix and use it, its very efficient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrecords/45428167#45428167

Comment: Thank you!! :) I'll look into that on some other time, right now, I'm working on the neural net itself, and training it.