# how to convert numpy to tfrecords and then generate batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

My question is about how to get batch inputs from multiple (or sharded) tfrecords. I've read the example https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py#L410. The basic pipeline is, take the training set as as example, (1) first generate a series of tfrecords (e.g., `train-000-of-005`, `train-001-of-005`, ...), (2) from these filenames, generate a list and fed them into the `tf.train.string_input_producer` to get a queue, (3) simultaneously generate a `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` to do other stuff, (4) using `tf.train.batch_join` to generate batch inputs.

I think this is complex, and I'm not sure the logic of this procedure. In my case, I have a list of `.npy` files, and I want to generate sharded tfrecords(multiple seperated tfrecords, not just one single large file). Each of these `.npy` files contains different number of positive and negative samples (2 classes). A basic method is to generate one single large tfrecord file. But the file is too large (`~20Gb`). So I resort to sharded tfrecords. Are there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The whole process is simplied using the `Dataset API`. Here are both the parts: `(1): Convert numpy array to tfrecords` and `(2): read the tfrecords to generate batches`.

## 1. **Creation of tfrecords from a numpy array:**

```
Example arrays:
inputs = np.random.normal(size=(5, 32, 32, 3))
labels = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(5,))

def npy_to_tfrecords(inputs, labels, filename):
  with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(filename) as writer:
    for X, y in zip(inputs, labels):
        # Feature contains a map of string to feature proto objects
        feature = {}
        feature['X'] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=X.flatten()))
        feature['y'] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[y]))

        # Construct the Example proto object
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

        # Serialize the example to a string
        serialized = example.SerializeToString()

        # write the serialized objec to the disk
        writer.write(serialized)


npy_to_tfrecords(inputs, labels, 'numpy.tfrecord')
```

## 2. **Read the tfrecords using the Dataset API:**

```
filenames = ['numpy.tfrecord']
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
# for version 1.5 and above use tf.data.TFRecordDataset

# example proto decode
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {'X':tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32),
                      'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)
    return parsed_features['X'], parsed_features['y']

# Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)  
  
# Generate batches
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
```

**Check the generated batches are proper:**

```
for data in dataset:
    break
np.testing.assert_allclose(inputs[0] ,data[0][0])
np.testing.assert_allclose(labels[0] ,data[1][0])
```

Comment: Hi, sir, does this api support the `num_threads` or `capacity` like that in the `tf.train.shuffle_batch` api? In my case, if the network is small, then the execution in GPU is faster than the data loading, which leads to idle GPU time. So I want to the queue for fetching data is always full. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks for this nice example - using `reader = tf.TFRecordReader(); key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)` I get a key, value pair back (value corresponds to `example_proto` in your code). How can I get the key using the `dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)` ?

Comment: is it possible to store "shapeofnparray" in the TFRecord and then reshape using it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603692/2184122 ? I can't map between the old and the dataset way.

Comment: What exactly is `example_proto`? A string or byte data? where is that variable assigned? what is it assigned to?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have some questions. Why did you flatten X? My numpy arrays are image arrays and I have 51 outputs for y. Do I also need to flatten them? moreover, when I try this code, ram goes as high as 90% (I have 32GB RAM) and the program crashes. Can you identify the problem?

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting `TypeError: array([ 3.,  9.,  3., ..., 17.,  8., 17.], dtype=float32) has type numpy.ndarray, but expected one of: int, long, float
` error on the statement `example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))`