# Import huge non-image dataset in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, hdf5

I have a big dataset (300.000 examples x 33.000 features), which of course does not fit the memory. The data are saved in HDF5 format. The values are mostly zeros (sparse data). They look like this:

```
           Attr1    52  52  52  52  52  52  52  52 ...
           Attr2    umb umb umb umb umb umb umb umb ...
           CellID   TGC-1 TGG-1 CAG-1 TTC-1 GTG-1 GTA-1 CAA-1 CAC-1 ...

Acc     Gene                                      ...
243485  RP11-.3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
237613  FAM138A     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
186092  OR4F5       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
238009  RP11-.7     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
239945  RP11-.8     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
279457  FO538.2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
228463  AP006.2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...
...     ...         ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I have done the following that works, to load the whole dataset in TensorFlow (`loompy` is just a package using hdf5 on the background):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import loompy as lp

batch_size = 1000

with loompy.connect(filename, 'r') as ds:
    ds_shape = (batch_size, ds.shape[0])
    ds_dtype = ds[0:1, 0:1].dtype

    labels = np.asarray([ds.ca.CellID, ds.ca.Attr1]).T
    labels_shape = (batch_size, 1)

data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(ds_dtype, ds_shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels[:,1].dtype, labels_shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with loompy.connect(filename, 'r') as ds:
        for i in range(0, ds.shape[1], batch_size):
            batch = ds[0 : ds_shape[1], i : i + batch_size].T
            batch_labels = np.asarray([ds.ca.CellID[i : i + batch_size],
                                       ds.ca.Attr1[i : i + batch_size]]).T[:,1]

            sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict = {data_placeholder: batch,
                       labels_placeholder: batch_labels.reshape(batch_size, 1)})

            for _ in range(batch_size):
                print(sess.run(next_element))
```

Output:

> (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), array([b'52'], dtype=object))
>
> (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), array([b'52'], dtype=object))
>
> ...

This way however, I am not able to split my data in train, test and evaluation sets. Also, I can only shuffle them inside each batch, which is not effective since most times the data on a batch belong to the same class.

How do I manipulate this kind of data to be able to load them as train, test, evaluation sets, and perform shuffling etc. (preferably by utilizing my TitanX GPU as much as possible)?

Comment: You may want to use tfrecords and store them in sparse features: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/SparseFeature

Comment: @vijaym The problem with TFRecords is that most examples are image related, so I haven't figured out how to do that with a dataset like this. Can you point me on the right sources?

Comment: You can check my answer for Numpy arrays, you may need to make some changes for sparse matrices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec

Comment: Are you open to making a second (shuffled and split) copy of the data on the disk? There are a number of large scale data processing tools that will do that for you.

Comment: @Omegastick I am open to everything that could work well. Can you name the tools you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there is someone still interested on this topic, here is my solution to this problem I had. In the end I stuck with Loompy file format, as it is really convenient with what I am doing (take a look on [Loompy here](http://linnarssonlab.org/loompy/index.html)). To import such a big volume of information in my model, I used the `from_generator()` function of the `tf.data.Dataset` TensorFlow API. Also, I created a generator to yield the data as needed.

Below is how my input function looks:

```
import loompy as lp
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

model_input_name = ""
input_size = 10000
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10

# Input functions for train, test and eval sets.
def train_input_fn():
    return _input_fn('TRAIN')

def test_input_fn():
    return _input_fn('TEST')

def eval_input_fn():
    return _input_fn('EVAL')

# General purpose input function
def _input_fn(mode = 'TRAIN'):

    """
        Arguments
            mode : 'TRAIN', 'TEST', 'EVAL'
    """

    # A generator to yield data and labels from the given FILE,
    # based on the indices assigned to the "indices" variable.
    # If you change the labels, remember to update the from_generator()
    # parameters below, to reflect their datatype.
    def gen():
        with lp.connect(FILE, 'r') as ds:
            if ae:
                for i in indices:
                    yield {model_input_name: ds[:, i]}, ds[:, i]
            else:
                for i in indices:
                    yield {model_input_name: ds[:, i]}, ds.ca.x_CellType[i]

    # Get the indices for train, test and eval sets
    train_idx, test_idx, eval_idx = train_test_set_idx_split(TRAIN_RT, TEST_RT, EVAL_RT)

    # Check condition and assign the respective set to the "indices" variable
    if mode == 'TRAIN':
        indices = train_idx
    elif mode == 'TEST':
        indices = test_idx
    elif mode == 'EVAL':
        indices = eval_idx
    else:
        print("Wrong mode choice: ", mode)
        exit(1)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, ({model_input_name: tf.int64}, tf.int64),
                                             output_shapes=({model_input_name: [input_size,]}, []))

    # Shuffle, batch, map, prefetch and repeat your dataset.
    # If you need to do some preprocessing on the data, create your function on
    # the cell above, and call it within a map() function.

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size*50)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    dataset = dataset.map(_reshape_labels)
    dataset = dataset.map(_int2float)

    # Map on whatever other functions you need
    dataset = dataset.map( ... )

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    return iterator.get_next()


# Get train, test, eval indices for the given dataset
def train_test_set_idx_split(train_rt, test_rt, eval_rt):
    """ This function returns indices for the train, test and evaluation sets,
        given an input Dataset.
        Arguments:
            train_rt: ratio of the train dataset
            test_rt:  ratio of the test dataset
            eval_rt:  ratio of the evaluation dataset

        Returns:
            train_idx: indices (of the given dataset) for the train dataset
            test_idx:  indices (of the given dataset) for the test dataset
            evel_idx:  indices (of the given dataset) for the evaluation dataset

        Note:
            This function will work correctly as long as (test_rt == evel_rt) is True.
            If you need (test_rt != evel_rt), you need something more sophisticated.
    """

    with lp.connect(FILE, 'r') as ds:
        idx = np.array(range(0, ds.shape[1]))

    train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(idx, train_size=train_rt, test_size=test_rt+eval_rt)
    test_idx, eval_idx = train_test_split(test_idx, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5)

    return train_idx, test_idx, eval_idx

# Reshape labels as needed
def _reshape_labels(data, labels):
    return data, tf.reshape(labels, (-1,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely try [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/), it allows you to work with data not fitting in memory and it paralyzes computation so that you can use all cores of your cpu. Also I recommend moving your data from hdf to [parquet](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-parquet-multithreading/), it allows concurrent reads and writes which speeds things up. Please see the link where Wes McKinney (pandas creator) goes in depth and compares it with other formats.

You could prepare snippets in Dask that prepare train, test and validation sets and read them without exceeding available memory.

Comment: How well are they blend with TensorFlow though? I couldn't find much info online, except some people experimenting with it. There's no much time for experimentation, I just want something that nicely works so I can focus on building the model.

Comment: As far as I know it does not blend whatsoever it library to process big amounts of data in parallel you would have to write a function that fits your needs there won't be anything pre-built to feed tensorflow models. Thankfully api is almost exactly the same as in pandas, so it is really straightforward.

Comment: Well the loom format I use works pretty much as a Pandas dataframe, but that doesn't help me import and do the processing I want to the data. I need an answer on how to treat such big data for doing different tasks (e.g. shuffling) in TensorFlow.

Comment: This is exactly why I recommend parquet + dask, it allows you to work with files much bigger than your RAM as if you would work with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

The gap between dask and machine learning frameworks like tensorflow is actually a distributed in-memory cache.

We can see that dask is a very good choice for the preprocessing part, but how to transfer the preprocessed data to tensorflow is what we are worrying about.

Vineyard(v6d.io) solves the intermediate data sharing problem by providing integrations with data engines like dask and ml engines like tf and pytorch.
Here is an example (https://v6d.io/examples/distributed-learning.html) showing how to transfer the preprocessed data from dask to horovod.keras, hope it helps.