# Using tfRecord files for time series with variable lags

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow for time-series predictions.
The time series used are of around 10,000 daily data points, that work just fine with the tf.Dataset API. 
To use intraday data (every 5 min), I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to import my data, as every time I re-initialize the dataset iterator I keep using feed_dicts (which are inefficient) pointing to my numpy array of training or validation set. This gets more important as I usually run the validation or test set after every epoch, meaning the iterators are reinitialized twice per epoch.

My data is imported usually like this:

```
   dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, 
   Y)).batch(batch_size)

   iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
   input, label = iterator.get_next()
```

where X and Y are placeholders.

Currently, my data is pre_processed using simple functions with numpy arrays, where I set the number of lags to explain a single time step (for example: [0,1,2] for the label [3]), which I also change every often to train.
Because I'm changing the lags of my input data, I dont have a fixed (feature,label) pair to construct my TfRecord file.

**My question is if it's worthy to create a Tfrecord file of just one feature (the original time series) to be modified into a (feature, label) pair depending of the lags I choose.**

I ask because it might be the time gained is not significant as the dataset should be mapped anyway, or that are other possible solutions (one idea that come to my mind is using `dataset.repeat()` and a `for epoch in range(num_batches):` instead of a while loop, though I think that it must be the same as reinitializing the iterator after every `Tf.OutOfRangeError` error, so no gain).

In case it's worthy to create the tfrecord file, can you provide some implementation using the dataset API? I've tried to create a single feature file similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428167) but without any solution as I can't parse the data correctly.

Ps: It's absurdly simple, but it's better to include the code to create my features, labes from a time series:

```
def lags(data, t_steps, label=False):
    data_=[]
    for i in range(len(data)-t_steps):
        if label:
            data_.append(data[i+t_steps])
        else:
            data_.append(data[i:i+t_steps])
    return np.array(data_)
```

where `t_steps` define the number of lags to use.