# writing numpy to tfrecord is slow when looping over features using tfrecordwriter

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have a numpy array that i want to write to a tfrecord file. The dimensions of the array for both `input X` and `label y` are `[200,46,72,72]`for the training of my model i want to read the tfrecord file to get slices of `[72,72]` both for input and label data.

I tried to apply the following [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec?rq=1)

The problem is that this method is really **slow** probably due to the amount of elements looped over `200*46`.
When I write the entire `numpy array` as feature of `bytes` instead of `floatlist` I don't have this problem, but than I don't understand how to get `[72,72]` slices for each batch.

```py
def npy_to_tfrecords(X,y):
    # write records to a tfrecords file
    output_file = 'E:\\Documents\\Datasets\\tfrecordtest\\test.tfrecord'
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)


    # Loop through all the features you want to write
    for i in range(X.shape[0]) :
         for j in range(X.shape[1]) :
            #let say X is of np.array([[...][...]])
            #let say y is of np.array[[0/1]]
            print(f"{i},{j}")
            # Feature contains a map of string to feature proto objects

            feature = {}
            feature['X'] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=X[i,j:,:].flatten()))
            feature['y'] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=y[i,j:,:].flatten()))

            # Construct the Example proto object
            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature= feature) )

            # Serialize the example to a string
            serialized = example.SerializeToString()

            # write the serialized objec to the disk
            writer.write(serialized)
    writer.close()
```

for reading i use the following code roughly

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=6)
dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(SHUFFLE_BUFFER))
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
input_data, label_data = iterator.get_next()
```

> when i save the `numpy arrays` as `bytes` the `parse_function` returns
>   the whole array and I can not figure out how to write a
>   `parse_function` that returns slices.

## Summary:

- save 2 `numpy arrays` to `tfrecord`
- read `tfrecord` file and obtain `slices` of the saved `numpy arrays` in the batches used for the model