# Handling large numpy array in tensorflow with regression output(51 outputs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I have a very large dataset which is a single npy file that contains around 1.5m elements each a 150x150x3 image. The output has 51 columns (51 outputs). Since the dataset can't fit into memory, How do I load it and use it to fit the model? An efficient way is using TFRecords and tf.data but I couldn't understand how to do this. I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: What does _I couldn’t understand how to do this_ mean? Can you share your attempts?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yeah sure, the idea is to convert the large dataset into a TensorFlow compatible format, TFRecord, and then use the tf.data API to read this tfrecord file to feed it to the neural network. I tried various approaches but failed to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to load your NPY file fragment by fragment ( to feed your neural network with) and not to load it into the memory at once. You can use `numpy.load` as normal and specify the `mmap_mode` keyword so that the array is kept on disk, and only necessary bits are loaded into memory upon access (more details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap))

```py
numpy.load(file, mmap_mode=None, allow_pickle=False, fix_imports=True, encoding='ASCII')
```

> Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory. NumPy’s memmap’s are array-like objects. This differs from Python’s mmap module, which uses file-like objects.

If you want to know how to create a `tfrecords` from a `numpy` array, and then read the `tfrecords` using the Dataset API, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec/45428167#45428167) provides a good answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try both methods

Comment: I have some questions about the link you provided for TFRecords. Why was X flattened? My numpy arrays are image arrays and I have 51 outputs for y. Do I also need to flatten them? moreover, when I try this code, ram goes as high as 90% (I have 32GB RAM) and the program crashes. Can you identify the problem?