# How to speed up tf.dataset creation and training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a labelled dataset for training purpose. In this dataset, I want to  label frames of a video with a specific number depicting the position of a dot.

Since the videos in total are around **1 hour** long, and with **25 frames per second (fps)**, the total number of frames exceed **100,000** and it takes over a day to just create the dataset.

I am using **tf.keras.image_dataset_from_directory** to create the dataset by reading the files directly and then, assigning it a label via a *numpy array* I have created. I wanted to ask if there is any faster way of creating datasets or merging tf.data.datasets together in a parallelised way.

Below is my code. (I am using Jupyter notebook on VSCode and python 3.9.7 and tf.version=2.0):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def print_dataset(data_set:tf.data.Dataset):
        iterator = data_set.as_numpy_iterator()
        # create a numpy array labelled
        images = np.empty((0, 108, 192, 1))
        labels = np.empty((0))
        for element in iterator:
                images = np.append(images, element[0], axis=0)
                labels = np.append(labels, element[1], axis=0)
              
        print(np.shape(images))
        print(np.shape(labels))
        plt.imshow(images[0])
        print(labels[0])
        return images, labels

# creating the frame dataset from directory
image = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'frames', labels=labels, label_mode='int', image_size=(108,192), color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=1) # frames directory contains the frames used for training.

print(image)
plt.show(image)

#generating the labelled dataset and getting the img as well as labels
img, labels= print_dataset(image)
)
```

Comment: You want to treat the dataset as video data, where the ordering of frames is important? or you want to treat it as images? If its the second case, then check-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrecords/45428167#45428167

Comment: One way, Can you try saving and loading these large videos as numpy arrays? Using `np.load` with `mmap_mode='r'` helps me read over 50 GB files in small ram constraints.